# Compile error in conditional when or-ing clauses

Tags: java, if-statement

This code:

```
class Foo { 
    public static void calculator(double BP, double Hr ) { 
        if (BP <8) || (Hr>60) {
            System.out.println("Not possible"); 
        }  
    }
}
```

Gives this error:

```
line no:3: illegal start of expression
if (BP <8)|| (Hr>60)
^
```

I want to add a condition where `if` should give message "Not possible".

Comment: Your parentheses are misplaced.

Comment: Your code formatting is terrible. Use of good formatting will help you spot this and similar errors immediately, and so please for your sake and ours, put in the effort to format your code, including indentation and use of parenthesis, properly.

Comment: Also at least syntax errors should be tackled on your own.

Comment: Please indent by 4 spaces to show code blocks / compiler output. That will your questions cleaner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition for an `if` statement must be completely surrounded by parentheses.

The way you have it, Java will interpret `(BP < 8)` as the condition, and `|| (Hr > 60)` doesn't make sense as the `if` statement body, so that explains the compiler error.

Try:

```
if ((BP < 8) || (Hr > 60))
```